# How to get the selected item in matching items of the list view using with pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Here is my sample code.I am learning the list view methods,I already posted one question,but i have a small doubt in my program.In my program after "fliter" i am getting the matched items of the word in that i want to choose the selected item using the enter key but it is printing the first item after selecting..I don't want to print the first item of the matched list..can any one please help me.Thank you in advance.

given below is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        hLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.filter = QPushButton("filter", self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.filter)
        self.filter.clicked.connect(self.filterClicked)

        self.list = QListView(self)

        vLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        vLayout.addWidget(self.list)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self.list)

        codes = [
            'windows',
            'windows xp',
            'windows7',
            'hai',
            'habit',
            'hack',
            'good'
        ]
        for code in codes:
            item = QStandardItem(code)
            self.model.appendRow(item)
        self.list.setModel(self.model)
        shorcut=QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return), self)
        shorcut.activated.connect(self.on_enter_pressed)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_enter_pressed(self):
        if len(self.lineEdit.text())>0:
            self.filterClicked()

    def filterClicked(self):
        filter_text = str(self.lineEdit.text()).lower()
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            if filter_text in str(self.model.item(row).text()).lower():
                self.list.setRowHidden(row, False)
                self.list.setFocus()
            else:
                self.list.setRowHidden(row, True)

        ix = self.list.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
        #here if i mentioned self.list.selectionModel().currentIndex() means it is automatically printing the first item in List_View
        # i dont want to print first item ...after slecting the item in list view i will press enter key then only i want to print the selected item name
        print ix.data()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i got this answer..thq eyllanesc sir,i refer all your previous answers related to list view..Thank you so much..

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        hLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.filter = QPushButton("filter", self)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.filter)
        self.filter.clicked.connect(self.filterClicked)

        self.list = QListView(self)

        vLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        vLayout.addWidget(self.list)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self.list)

        codes = [
            'windows',
            'windows xp',
            'windows7',
            'hai',
            'habit',
            'hack',
            'good'
        ]
        for code in codes:
            item = QStandardItem(code)
            self.model.appendRow(item)
        self.list.setModel(self.model)
        shorcut=QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return), self)
        shorcut.activated.connect(self.on_enter_pressed)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_enter_pressed(self):
        if len(self.lineEdit.text())>0:
            self.filterClicked()

    def filterClicked(self):
        filter_text = str(self.lineEdit.text()).lower()
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            if filter_text in str(self.model.item(row).text()).lower():
                self.list.setRowHidden(row, False)
                self.list.setFocus()
            else:
                self.list.setRowHidden(row, True)
        indexes =  self.list.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
        for index in indexes:
            print index.data().toString()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```